# @Valid: Expecting an error message but nothing happens

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation

I am using Spring Security 3 with Spring Security 6 and I have a problem with validations.

My pom.xml contains the following:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
  <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

My controller:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
@Validated
public class AuthController {
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> login(@Valid @RequestBody CustomUserDetails user) { // @Valid is from jakarta.validation

        System.out.println(user.getUsername());
        return ResponseEntity.ok("token");
    }
}
```

My User class:

```java
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @NotBlank(message = "username is mandatory")
    @Email(message = "username should be a valid email address")
    private String username;

    @NotBlank(message = "password is mandatory")
    @Size(min = 8, message = "password length should be at least 8 characters")
    private String password;
```

UserDetails:

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CustomUserDetails implements UserDetails {
    @NotBlank(message = "username is mandatory")
    @Email(message = "username should be a valid email address")
    private String username;

    @NotBlank(message = "password is mandatory")
    @Size(min = 8, message = "password length should be at least 8 characters")
    private String password;
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong, but I don't receive anything. No error, no exception, nothing.

I also tried it with this exception handler:

```java
    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleValidationException(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
        Map<String, String> errors = new HashMap<>();
        ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors().forEach(error -> errors.put(error.getField(), error.getDefaultMessage()));
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(errors);
    }
```

But still, nothing happens. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Remove `@Validated ` from your controller because validated is used for a single parameter but for request body `@validate` is used in the argument.

Comment: @FarhaMansuri I tried that but still the same issue.

Comment: Remove the `validation-api` dependency that is already part of the `spring-boot-starter-validation` dependency. You probably added it because you are following old tutorial and decided (yourself) to use the newest Spring Boot version (3) instead of 2. If you get compilation errors (and you will) fix those by replacing `javax.validation` with `jakarta.validation`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
        @RestController
        @RequestMapping("/")
        public class AuthController {
            @PostMapping("/login")
            public ResponseEntity<Object> login(@Valid @RequestBody CustomUserDetails user) { 
                System.out.println(user.getUsername());
                return ResponseEntity.ok("token");
            }
        }
```

Comment: He uses Spring Boot 3, which supports JakartaEE **not** JavaEE.